# perl to merge csv files removing the headings

Tags: perl, csv, merge

I have several monthly reports in csv format in a folder. The csv files all have 8 common columns (with headings) . Using perl, I would like to merge these files together line by line.

say

**file 1:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,
```

**file 2:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,
```

I would like the output to look something like that (join the rows and remove the headings)

**output:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,
```

I have managed to save the names of the files in an array. but for some reason, I could not join them. 
can you please help me figure out what is wrong with my code. I am quite new to perl.

```
#! C:Strawberry/perl/bin;
use feature ':5.12';
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_directory = 'R:/testing_data/';

opendir( DIR, $data_directory ) or die "Could not open $data_directory $!\n";
my @files = grep {/_monthlyreport\.csv$/} readdir(DIR);    #to get on the monthly reports csv files

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open( HANR, "<", '$data_directory' . my $files ) or die "cannot open $files: $!";    #read handler
    open( HANW, ">>", "G:/outputfile_script.csv" ) or die "error $! \n"; #write handler for creating new sorted files
    my @lines = ();
    @lines = <HANR>;

    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        chomp($line);
        my $count++;
        next unless $count;    # skip header i.e the first line containing stock details
        print HANW join $line, "\n";
    }

    my $count = -1;
    close(HANW);
    close(HANR);
}

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `open` statement to your input filehandle is malformed, and `my $count++;` is also broken.

I'd also recommend modernizing your code by using lexical file handles.  The following is a cleaned up version of your code:

```perl
use feature ':5.12';
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $data_directory = 'R:/testing_data/';

opendir my $dh, "$data_directory";

open my $outfh, ">>", "G:/outputfile_script.csv";
my $seenheader = 0;

while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
    next unless $file =~ /_monthlyreport\.csv$/;

    open my $infh, '<', "$data_directory/$file";
    while (<$infh>) {
        print $outfh $_ if $. > 1 || ! $seenheader++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i am however getting some errors:syntax error at G:\scriptnew.plx line 16, near "open "
Can't use global $. in "my" at G:\scriptnew.plx line 18, near "if $. "
Execution of G:\scriptnew.plx aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Was just missing a semicolon after the `next` line.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter and stop printing if the counter equals 0;

```
#! C:Strawberry/perl/bin;
use feature ':5.12';
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_directory = 'R:/testing_data/';

opendir(DIR,$data_directory) or die "Could not open $data_directory $!\n";
my @files = grep {/_monthlyreport\.csv$/} readdir(DIR); #to get on the monthly reports csv files

foreach my $file (@files) {

                    open(HANR ,"<",'$data_directory'.my $files) or die "cannot open $files: $!";                        #read handler 
                    open(HANW , ">>","G:/outputfile_script.csv") or die "error $! \n";          #write handler for creating new sorted files
                    my @lines=();
                    @lines=<HANR>;
         my $i =0;

        foreach my $line (@lines){

                next if ($i==0) ;
                                chomp ($line) ; 
                                my $count++;
                                next unless $count;                                              # skip header i.e the first line containing stock details
                                print HANW join $line,"\n";
                                }

        my $count= -1;
        close(HANW);
        close(HANR);
                   }

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help jens! the code is still not perfectly working. Could you possibly help me fix it. I am getting:Global symbol "$files" requires explicit package name at G:\script1.plx line 13.

Bareword "i" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at G:\script1.plx line 21.
Execution of G:\script1.plx aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @fmfshog: Sorry my mistake. I have changed my answer: (next if ($i==0) )

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong.

```
open(HANR ,"<",'$data_directory'.my $files) or die "cannot open $files: $!";
```

Should be

```
open(HANR ,"<","$data_directory".$files) or die "cannot open $files: $!";
```